# trouble importing jquery into wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, import

i have a really annoying problem with wordpress built-in jquery. I have read dozen of articles on the subject of properly registering and calling registered jquery scripts using the functions.php (the code is shown below), but it can't seem to work anyway I try it. Can you please explain to me what did I do wrong, I checked every file path that is hooked to wp_register_script, wp_head in header.php is in place, spelling is correct... I cannon think of the possible reason why none of the jquery plugins listed below won't work on my page, it's frustrating. Here is the link to my website, if it could help you (http://yuagro.eu.pn/wordpress). Many thanks.

// REGISTROVANJE JQUERY BIBLIOTEKA U WORDPRESSU

```
<?php
    function jquery_biblioteke() {

    wp_register_script( 'sticky-nav', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.sticky.js', array('jquery') ); 
    wp_register_script( 'basic-slider', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/bjqs-1.3.min.js', array('jquery') );
    wp_register_script( 'modern-ticker', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.modern-ticker.min.js', array('jquery') );
    wp_register_style( 'modern-tickerjs', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/modern-ticker.js', array('modern-ticker') );
    wp_register_script( 'easySlider', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/easySlider1.7.js', array('jquery') );


    wp_enqueue_script('sticky-nav');
    wp_enqueue_script( 'basic-slider' );
    wp_enqueue_script('modern-ticker');
    wp_enqueue_script('modern-tickerjs');
    wp_enqueue_script('easySlider');

    }

    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts','jquery_biblioteke');

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

i checked your link, check console and it said 'jQuery not defined', have you include jQuery library ie `wp_enqueue_script('jquery');`

Comment: no, I haven't included jquery library on top, but I suppose it automatically gets called by the array('jquery') in the wp_register_script tag. I will certainly try this now, and get back to you :)

Comment: so I included jQuery library as you said, but the console is still showing the 'jQuery not defined' error on lines 20, 35 and 42. And these are the calls for the jquery plugins that I want to use on my site, and they are embedded in index.php directly, to be precise, in the header.php right below the links for different stylesheets, you can see these lines if you view Page Source in Firefox (I'm using Web Developer add-on, you can view this in whatever browser you're using currently).

Answer (score 0):

hmmm I never register them just enque them with the path, like so:

```
<?php
function jquery_biblioteke() {

wp_enqueue_script( 'sticky-nav', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.sticky.js', array('jquery') ); 
wp_enqueue_script( 'basic-slider', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/bjqs-1.3.min.js', array('jquery') );
wp_enqueue_script( 'modern-ticker', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.modern-ticker.min.js', array('jquery') );
wp_enqueue_script( 'modern-tickerjs', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/modern-ticker.js', array('modern-ticker') );
wp_enqueue_script( 'easySlider', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/easySlider1.7.js', array('jquery') );


}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts','jquery_biblioteke');

?>
```

Comment: I will try this approach also, because all this about jquery and wordpress is really getting on my nerves, so to speak, it's stopping my project BIG TIME. :) pozdrav i hvala na odgovoru ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
```

Add this on top of your wordpress functiion

Comment: thank you very much guys (and girls) :D, you helped me a LOT. I solved my problem, and I have gained a very useful knowledge that will help my in all of my future project. So this is the final code, I have applied Bojana's advice about just using the wp_enqueue_script, gwillie's advice was useful because it reminded me to remove all of the <script> tags from my header.php and put them all in functions.php template. And at the end, added the wp_enqueue_script('jquery'); on top of my function, @wordpresser.